# How to Join two tables in HQL,which doesn't have relationship in Database

Tags: hibernate, hql, nhibernate-hql

Could you please let me know will it possible to have a join in HQL hibernate, which doesn't have any table relationship in Database?

Comment: How would you join them? Do they have anything in common? You need to show us how your tables look like. Please take your time to ask the question. The more informations you provide the easier it is for others to help you. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a cartesian join with a condition in the where like this :

```
select e1.id,e2.id from Entity1 e1, Entity2 e2 where e1.fieldX=e2.fieldY
```